# Heroku app not working after rails upgraded to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am getting this error at `Heroku logs`. I ve updated the rails version to `3.2.11` and then updated the `bootstrap` as `Heroku`people have mentioned this that there are some  security issues with the `Rails 3.2.10`. The error is as follows.

```
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
 2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
 2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
 2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
 2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
 2013-01-11T18:07:53+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
 2013-01-11T18:07:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
 2013-01-11T18:07:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
 2013-01-11T18:07:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
 2013-01-11T18:07:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 2013-01-11T18:07:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
 2013-01-11T18:07:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
 2013-01-11T18:07:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 12676`
 2013-01-11T18:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
 2013-01-11T18:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
 2013-01-11T18:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
 2013-01-11T18:08:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 2013-01-11T18:08:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:12676
 2013-01-11T18:08:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
 2013-01-11T18:08:17+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
 2013-01-11T18:08:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections (PGError)
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__431883729642635568__prepare__3624875479622533686__callbacks'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
 2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.3/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-11T18:08:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-01-11T18:08:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-11T18:08:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-01-11T18:08:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=photography-ahmadhamza.herokuapp.com fwd=116.202.185.14 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-01-11T18:08:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=photography-ahmadhamza.herokuapp.com fwd=116.202.185.14 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-01-11T18:09:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=photography-ahmadhamza.herokuapp.com fwd=116.202.185.14 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-01-11T18:12:03+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=photography-ahmadhamza.herokuapp.com fwd=116.202.185.14 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-01-11T18:12:03+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=photography-ahmadhamza.herokuapp.com fwd=116.202.185.14 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I m getting mad on this. Please help. After few mins the site is loading but the js is not working. I m using the carousel which is not working at all. The other part of JS is working.

Comment: The error was very stupid... Its a typo actually.thanks for the advice.

Comment: What kind of error was that? I have the same issue after upgrade to rails 3.2.11. Thx.

Comment: Actually there was a mistake in my code.. Spelling mistake.. i defined some class in css of different spelling "carousell" and call that class in view with different spelling "caraousel". So that why this error came out?

Answer (score 0):

May be Heroku hasn't yet released support for 3.2.11

Comment: there's no support requirement needed by Heroku for 3.2.11

Comment: heroku only sent me mail to upgrade the version of rails.